# How to print values and keys into two columns with appropriate space between them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that contains keys as a words and values as a numbers.

```
d = dict(bag.items())
```

How can I print keys and values into two columns, where the second column has the width of the longest key and all values are printed by right side?

```
 10     potatoes
  8       tomato
  5        onion
  3        plate
  2          ham
  1         meat
```

I tried with this:

```
for k, v in bag.items():
    print(v, k)
```

But I have to find a way to set values by right side, so make appropiate spaces between keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

Establish maximum widths, and [format](https://pyformat.info/) string with them:

```
mkey = max(map(len, (map(str, bag.keys()))))
mval = max(map(len, (map(str, bag.values()))))

for k, v in bag.items():
    print('  {:>{}}    {:>{}}'.format(k, mkey, v, mval))
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki it is not a trick; it just specifies that the width for indent (`:>width`) is a variable in the formatting itself, so eventually it becomes `{k:>mkey}`, that with `k='hi'` and `mkey=4` become `'  hi'`.

Comment: Ok, just found [this link](https://pyformat.info/) where they explain all the formatting options. Maybe you want to include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in this way:

```
bag = {'tomato': 15, 'onion': 3,'potatoes': 7, 'ham': 2}
bag_values = []

longest = ""
for k in bag:
    if len(k) > len(longest):
        longest = k

longest_v = ""
for k, v in bag.items():
    bag_values.append(str(v))

for value in bag_values:
    if len(value) > len(longest_v):
        longest_v = value

space = " "
a = (len(7*space)+len(longest_v)+len(longest))


for k, v in bag.items():
    c = len(longest) - len(k)
    b = len(longest_v) - len(str(v))
    print((3+b)*space + str(v) + (4+c)*space + k)
```